# How to display the value of Last Analysis date on Sonar Dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I would like to display somehow on a Sonar dashboard the Last Analysis date.
We use SonarQube Version 5.6.3.

**EDIT**

Can I display the Last Analysis date somehow on the Quality Gate widget?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Last Analysis date is displayed on the top right of any project page you would browse in SonarQube ( [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00rEv.png) ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is not fits to what we would like to display. Could you please check my EDITED post?

Answer (score 1):

Was also looking for this question but found the workaround to 
use: **Advanced Timeline Chart** instead of Quality Gate widget. I adapted the height but anyway a lot of white space.

[image]